# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException errors while running testng.xml

Tags: java, testng

I am getting following error while running testng.xml

> ant run_testNG

```
Buildfile: build.xml
run_testNG:
   [testng] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   [testng]     at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:189)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:351)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:854)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1178)
   [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1137)
   [testng] The tests failed.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

## my testng.xml looks like :

```
<project default="test">

 <path id="cp">
   <pathelement location="/softwares/lib/testng-5.13.1.jar"/>
   <pathelement location="/softwares/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.3/run_test/run_test/build"/>
 </path>

 <taskdef name="testng" classpathref="cp" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />

 <target name="test">
   <testng classpathref="cp" groups="fast">
     <classfileset dir="build" includes="com/example/test/*.class"/>
   </testng>
 </target>

</project>
```

## my build.xml file is:

```
<property name="lib.dir"   value="/softwares/lib"/>
<property name="src.dir" value="/softwares/src" />
```

```
<target name="run_testNG" description="Run TestNG">
    <testng classpathref="compile.classpath" haltOnfailure="false">
        <xmlfileset dir="/softwares/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.3/run_test/" includes="testng.xml" />
    </testng>
</target>
<target name="start-server">
    <java jar="/softwares/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.0b2.jar" fork="true" spawn="true">
        <arg line="-timeout 30"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.corporate.com"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Dhttp.proxyPort=3128"/>
    </java>
</target>
<target name="stop-server">
    <get taskname="selenium-shutdown"
        src="http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer"
        dest="result.txt" ignoreerrors="true" />
    <echo taskname="selenium-shutdown" message="DGF Errors during shutdown are expected" />
</target>
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="/softwares/selenium/selenium-2.0b2/libs/testng-5.14.1.jar" />
```

Can anybody help me...why I am getting this error. Your help will be appreciated

Comment: What do the calls in Parser.java and TestNG.java look like?
the NullPointerException does not come from the XML, but from the JAVA code

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that that is not a testng XML file.  It is an Ant build file.

For information on what a real testng XML file should look like, see [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml).  Alternatively, rename the file and use Ant to run the tests; e.g.

```
$ mv testng.xml build.xml
$ ant test
```

---

However, it is curious that testng fails in such a spectacular way when you give it an XML file that it doesn't grok.  Insufficient testing perhaps?  :-)

Comment: Correct, it looks like your testng.xml file is actually a build.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as if it can't find your `testng.xml` file. That's one possible reason for a NPE thrown by a XML Parser:  a `null` input. I see that `ant` defaults to `build.xml`. Do you have a `build.xml` file too?

Look at the `run_testNG` script, may be you can/have to add a full path to your file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
but found I was picking up a dbUnit dataset file that happend to match the pattern I had set up to pick up testng xml file (*test.xml). 
Simply renamed the file and I was good to go.

Hope this helps, even though the question was asked a while ago.